# Django and Postgres, OperationalError when deleting an object

Tags: django, postgresql, docker

I have a Django app and a Postgres DB deployed and dockerized. This is my **docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'

services:
  web:
    build: .
    container_name: web
    command: python manage.py migrate
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - ./src:/src
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - postgres
  postgres:
    image: postgres:latest
    container_name: postgres
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: my_user
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: my_secret_pass!
      POSTGRES_DB: my_db
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
```

Everything works great, I can create, update or delete objects of any of my 10 apps, however, when I try to delete an object of the class `Story`, which is the following, it fails:

```
class Story(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=255)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="stories", null=True, blank=True)
```

There are also a few other classes that have a ForeignKey to Story, such as Like, View or Comment.

My problem is that I get an operational error whenever I try to delete a Story. The funny fact is that I can create or update as many stories as I want, just not delete them.

When I try to delete any story, I get the following exception:

> OperationalError: FATAL:  the database system is in recovery mode

If I look at the queries performed, I see nothing wrong:

```
DELETE FROM "votes_like" WHERE "votes_like"."story_id" IN (91)  
DELETE FROM "comments_comment" WHERE "comments_comment"."story_id" IN (91)  
DELETE FROM "stories_story" WHERE "stories_story"."id" IN (91)
```

And then:

```
OperationalError: server closed the connection unexpectedly
This probably means the server terminated abnormally before or while processing the request.

server process was terminated by signal 11: Segmentation fault
```

And the story, the comments, the views or the likes it had, remains as usual.

I don't experience this behaviour in localhost under the same dockerized setup.

I've also tried to delete the row using raw SQL in the console, but it doesn't work, the connection gets closed.

Postgres logs:

```
2018-11-30 16:09:58.980 UTC [1] LOG:  server process (PID 3679) was terminated by signal 11: Segmentation fault
2018-11-30 16:09:58.980 UTC [1] DETAIL:  Failed process was running: COMMIT
2018-11-30 16:09:58.980 UTC [1] LOG:  terminating any other active server processes
2018-11-30 16:09:58.980 UTC [3588] WARNING:  terminating connection because of crash of another server process
2018-11-30 16:09:58.980 UTC [3588] DETAIL:  The postmaster has commanded this server process to roll back the current transaction and exit, because another server process exited abnormally and possibly corrupted shared memory.
2018-11-30 16:09:58.980 UTC [3588] HINT:  In a moment you should be able to reconnect to the database and repeat your command.
2018-11-30 16:09:58.980 UTC [3594] WARNING:  terminating connection because of crash of another server process
2018-11-30 16:09:58.980 UTC [3594] DETAIL:  The postmaster has commanded this server process to roll back the current transaction and exit, because another server process exited abnormally and possibly corrupted shared memory.
2018-11-30 16:09:58.980 UTC [3594] HINT:  In a moment you should be able to reconnect to the database and repeat your command.
2018-11-30 16:09:58.980 UTC [3595] WARNING:  terminating connection because of crash of another server process
2018-11-30 16:09:58.980 UTC [3595] DETAIL:  The postmaster has commanded this server process to roll back the current transaction and exit, because another server process exited abnormally and possibly corrupted shared memory.
2018-11-30 16:09:58.980 UTC [3595] HINT:  In a moment you should be able to reconnect to the database and repeat your command.
2018-11-30 16:09:58.981 UTC [3584] WARNING:  terminating connection because of crash of another server process
2018-11-30 16:09:58.981 UTC [3584] DETAIL:  The postmaster has commanded this server process to roll back the current transaction and exit, because another server process exited abnormally and possibly corrupted shared memory.
2018-11-30 16:09:58.981 UTC [3584] HINT:  In a moment you should be able to reconnect to the database and repeat your command.
2018-11-30 16:09:58.984 UTC [1] LOG:  all server processes terminated; reinitializing
2018-11-30 16:09:58.998 UTC [3680] LOG:  database system was interrupted; last known up at 2018-11-30 15:51:05 UTC
2018-11-30 16:09:59.000 UTC [3681] FATAL:  the database system is in recovery mode
2018-11-30 16:09:59.708 UTC [3682] FATAL:  the database system is in recovery mode
2018-11-30 16:10:00.204 UTC [3680] LOG:  database system was not properly shut down; automatic recovery in progress
2018-11-30 16:10:00.211 UTC [3680] LOG:  redo starts at 0/554D028
2018-11-30 16:10:00.212 UTC [3680] LOG:  invalid record length at 0/5558040: wanted 24, got 0
2018-11-30 16:10:00.212 UTC [3680] LOG:  redo done at 0/5558018
2018-11-30 16:10:00.212 UTC [3680] LOG:  last completed transaction was at log time 2018-11-30 16:09:58.810025+00
2018-11-30 16:10:00.275 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
```

Any hints? I've been trying to solve this problem for days but I have no idea on how to proceed.

Comment: Do you have the postgres log output? What privileges does the user have in non-localhost (production?) mode? Are you really running the production postgres with its data directory inside the docker container (meaning data is lost on container restart)?

Comment: It has not been deployed to production yet, but this is a production-like environment, I will add the volumes as soon as I get this working. 

I will also try to get the logs and the privileges and edit the question.

Comment: You have to delete the container to add the volumes.  If the data there is “important” I’d do this sooner rather than later.

Comment: I will do that, I also edited the question and added the logs.

Comment: "segmentation fault" indicates problems with the data files. So maybe stopping and restarting the docker container has already corrupted your data. From a quick look, timezone/time changes can break the transaction logs. (The logs you have posted seem not that helpfull - maybe you can increase the log output?)

Comment: It is weird, those are really all the logs I have, If I reproduce the issue, I get the same thing back, just several times, I updated the question.

Comment: Shall I just restart or rebuild my Postgres container?

Comment: **Volume** Dalvtor, you need to configure a volume to keep your data outside container. https://github.com/sameersbn/docker-postgresql/blob/master/docker-compose.yml - last line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future reference, the problem was fixed after doing a docker-compose down and docker-compose up, but the most important thing, UPDATING from (PostgreSQL) 11.0 to (PostgreSQL) 11.1!

More information: https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/issues/520